# Is there a way for a validator to get the current time?

Tags: slottime, on-chain, validation, time, posixtime

Is it possible for a validator to get the current time without it being passed in via the redeemer? My validator is heavily dependent on the time being correct so it would probably be a bad design choice to allow the wallet to pass in the time, as it can lie about the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to handle time in Plutus is using Slot ranges. This means that the script does not query the time. Instead it checks that the validation happens in a given slot interval that corresponds to a time.
You can have a look at the [notes about slots](https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/lectures/Lecture3.html) from the Plutus Pioneers Course.

With these slots, you can ensure that the validation takes place before, after or in a certain slot interval. And when you are sure that the validation takes place in a specific time interval, you also know the corresponding time. Each slot corresponds to one second as described [here](https://docs.cardano.org/new-to-cardano/cardano-nodes#howdoesitwork?).

Comment: Perfect. Your response captures everything I questioning!

Answer (score 1):

How about parameterizing the validator with `Slot` or `POSIXTime` and passing the current time from the contract to the validator script using `Contract.currentTime` or `Contract.currentSlot`?

That way, the wallet has no influence on it.

Comment: I could do this, but the issue is that the contract I am creating has quite a lot of different deadlines floating around. So asking for all of these up front would be annoying for someone using it and could allow for more mistakes/vulnerabilities.